# Xamarin recyler view issue with namespace

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, namespaces

xamarin Android using recyclerview 
Issue with namespace 
I have tried installing appcompat but couldn't solve the problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: Install the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView` package

Comment: Please improve the question by explaining what the issue is. It might help the community later.

Comment: Sushi, I tried  installing Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, but didn't solve the problem.                                                                               My sample project  is  in MVVM so probelm solved by installing  MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.